# What is the difference between Cross Fade and Gamma Cross Fade effect in Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

The docs mention only very briefly this difference: "The Gamma Cross transition is similar to the Cross Strip transition, however, the Gamma Cross strip transition uses color correction while transitioning between the two strips, resulting in a smoother transition that is easier on the eyes."

In practice, it is very hard to see any difference. What does it mean "uses color correction"? Does anyone know about a use case in which the difference is very noticeable?

Answer (score 2):

Mix colors from different channels, for example, Red and Green you will see that the result is slightly darker that you may expect:

[image]
[image]

So the difference between two cross is in how much color shifts

Comment: Thanks. Is this then the same as for example adding a brightness/contrast modifier?